# VSCode automatically removes new lines

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

I'm currently building an app using Python and Django. And when I am writing in my HTML files, I am putting some Jinja templating logic in it. Well, when I hit save in VSCode, it automatically pushes it back up a line and it's incredibly hard to read that way. I have examples below to show what I mean.

#### Before

So this is before I hit save and what I want it to look like.
[[image]]

#### After

This is after I hit save.

[[image]]

I am sure there's either a super simple setting I can change (which I've tried looking through). Or a plugin that I can install. But if there are neither, maybe I'll have to build my own plugin?? haha

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 Snippets, Code Runner, empty-indent, Indenticator, Jinja, JS-CSS-HTML Formatter, MagicPython, Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File -> Preferences -> User Settings.
You probably have this line:
`"editor.formatOnSave": true`.

You should change the value to `false` if you don't want VS Code to format your code.